php curl receveive 302 response code from OVH
In the last few days/weeks, a webservice call from php curl to a service located in OVH has started receiving a "302" HTTP Code response
I thought the calling server was blacklisted.
But the same service called from the same server on command line (curl -V ...) receives a good (400 code) response

302 is a redirect. Use CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION to automatically follow it.

Also I wouldn't consider at 400 response "good" either, as it means "Bad Request".

After a lot of debugging, tracing, it comes from the useragent
Curl called from command line send a default useragent string (like curl/7.41)
phpcurl by default send no user agent , and now OVH refuse this calls
I simply added :
$ch = curl_init(wswwwurl); 
/* !!! useragent is now MANDATORY when calling OVH !!! */ 
$config['useragent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:17.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/17.0';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $config['useragent']);

And it's now ok again !
rem : I tried to add CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, but then OVH server redirects to another page "blocked request"
